# Does "he yelled at me for help" mean he is in trouble or he is angry?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

> ​[yell](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/yell_1?q=yell): to shout loudly, for example because you are angry, excited,
> frightened or in pain
>
> **yell (at somebody/something)** He yelled at
> the other driver.
>
> **yell at somebody to do something** She yelled at the child to get
> down from the wall.
> **yell with something** They yelled with excitement.
>
> **yell out (in something)** She yelled out in pain.  + speech ‘Be
> careful!’ he yelled.
>
> **yell something (at somebody/something)** The crowd yelled encouragement at the players.
> **yell out something** He yelled out her name.
>
> **yell for something** He yelled for help.

As mentioned in the dictionary, there are many structures with **yell**.

Also, "**yell**" could mean the person is angry or frightened.

When we say "**He yelled for help**", most of us will think that he is frightened and in trouble.

Say, a child is naughty, angry now and wants you to help him to clean his room. The child then yells at his mom.

Do we say "**the child yelled for help**"?

Or **are different structures used depending on whether the person is angry or frightened?**

We might use different structures to express that situation.

For example,  "**the child yelled at his mom for help**" or "**the child yelled at his mom to help him**"

Note: Some native speakers say "**he yelled *to* me to help him**" or "**he yelled *to* me for help**".

Answer (score 0):

When we say "He yelled for help" we assume that he wants help very badly and we infer that that the person is in trouble.

But are you familiar with the "boy who yelled 'Wolf'"?  A young shepherd yells "Wolf" as a prank.  So we might have inferred that the boy was in trouble, when in truth the boy was not in trouble.

The direct meaning of "yell for help" is to call because you are in trouble.  But, of course you could be lying or pretending.  If you are yelling just because you want your Mum to help you clean your room, this is a type of pretending.